# Tutorials about ergodicity of $\textbf{Continuous}$ Markov processes

Tags: markov-process, ergodic-theory

Can someone recommend me some books / tutorials about
 Ergodicity of $\textbf{Continuous}$ Markov Processes (not about ergodicity of Markov Chains)?

P.S. I'm interested to contain ergodic properties, Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem, Krylov-Bogoliubov Theorem etc.

Thank you!

Comment: When you say "continuous," do you mean in time, or in space? For example, do you mean continuous time Markov chains with a discrete state space? Or do you mean Markov processes (in either continuous or discrete time) with uncountably infinite state spaces?  The former class of problems seem simpler, and results can often be obtained in terms of the embedded discrete time system.

Comment: Markov processes with continuous time  and uncountably infinite state space.

Comment: If there is a single state that is positive recurrent, you can use standard renewal theory (regardless of the state space cardinality).  Else, it is more complex.  The book by Meyn and Tweedie deals with these things. Also google phrases like "Harris recurrence."